# <select> tag not appearing through jquery in material design

Tags: jquery, material-design, codeigniter-3

When I go for showing select tag depending on the data what I choose is not getting on the view page but when I console it am getting exact result.Here is my code please have a look.

```
<?php if(empty($assign_vehicle_info)){?>
     <div class="input-field col s12" id="vh">
          <select  required name="vehicle_id" id="vehicle">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          </select>
        <label>Select Vehicle</label>
     </div>
<?php }?>

<script>
  $('#type').change(function(){

    var type=$('#type').val();
    alert(type);
    var url='<?php echo base_url();?>admin/vehicle/ajax_vehicle';

    $.post(url,{type:type}, function(data)
    {  
      $("#vehicle").html(data);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is my controller

```
public function ajax_vehicle()
{
    $data['vehicle']=$this->Vehicle_model->view_available_vehicles($_POST['type']);
    $this->load->view('admin/vehicle/ajax_vehicle',$data);
}
```

Here is my `ajax_view` vehicle

```
<select  required name="vehicle_id">
 <option value="">Select</option>
   <?php  if(empty($assign_vehicle_info)){
   if (!empty($vehicle)) {
   foreach ($vehicle as $veh) {?>
   <option value="<?= $veh->id ?>"<?php if (!empty($assign_vehicle_info)) {   echo $assign_vehicle_info->vehicle_id == $veh->id ? 'selected' : ''; } ?>><?= $veh->name ?></option>
  <?php }}}?>
 </select>
```

when I console it am getting result like this

[image]

am getting confused why its not getting viewed on the page.please help me to solve

Comment: anybody have any idea

Answer (score 0):

do you mean it is hidden, but you can see it in the inspector?
is the problem in retrieving data?
try for example:

```
 $("#vehicle").text(data);
```

Editing:
Try to retrieve the `<select>` element

```
  $("#vh").html(data);
```

Comment: yaa its hidden but i can see it in the inspector